Full text search, not finding subitems
I have setup Microsoft SQL Server full text search on a few tables.
These tables contain numbers, like phone numbers.
If I do a contains search on the full number, it returns matches, but not on a subset. Is this expected?
This SQL statement returns some values:
select distinct a.id 
from ml 
inner join a on ml.article_id = a.id 
where (contains(description, '123456789')
       or contains(name, '123456789') 
       or contains(notes, '123456789')) 
order by a.id desc;

This code however returns nothing:
select distinct a.id 
from ml 
inner join a on ml.article_id = a.id 
where (contains(description, '456789')
       or contains(name, '456789') 
       or contains(notes, '456789')) 
order by a.id desc;

This also returns nothing:
select distinct a.id 
from ml 
inner join a on ml.article_id = a.id 
where (contains(description, '"*456789"')
       or contains(name, '"*456789"') 
       or contains(notes, '"*456789"')) 
order by a.id desc;


Numbers, by default, are stop words; FTS is designed for words and numbers aren't words. Though, I just admit, having a FTS on phone numbers seems like an odd choice.

I understand your point, but it's just free text... ppl will write please Mr zyz call +.... sometimes they'll want to search for xyz, sometime for +... or part of it.

Sounds like you need to fix your design and put phone numbers in an appropriate column; classic XY Problem.

You may be searching free text but it's not a free text search. The specifics of how they do this varies, but generally speaking Full Text Search engines use word breakers to split words and stop lists to ignore words when building and updating their search catalogs. This often leads to issues like being unable to search for dotted quad IP addresses, e.g.: 10.20.30.40, because they're no longer single words in the catalog and the segments themselves may not even be included in the catalog as individual components.

If the text is excluded because of stopwords then you can't get around that by using freetext because the text simply isn't in the index. You anyway can't use a suffix search in FTS, only a prefix search, this is not unique to numbers. You should reread the docs on Full Text https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search?view=sql-server-ver16
